# Why am I getting a "declaration is incompatible with (x)"?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm creating a class called person right now in separate header and cpp files.
And for one of the functions I'm getting this error:

> declaration is incompatible with "Person::stat Person::getStat()" (declared at line 26 of "C:...")

(Not the exact directory but you get the idea)

Here is the code in the header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
class Person
{
public:
    struct stat {
        int str;
        int end;
        int dex;
        int intel;      
    };
    Person();
    ~Person();
    //properties
    stat getStat();
};
```

Here is the code in the cpp file:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Person.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Person::Person()
    :age(12), height(0)
{
}


Person::~Person()
{
}

struct stat Person::getStat() {

}
```

I'm getting the error with the getStat() function. I've tried including the string and iostream headers in both file and also only in the header file since a similar post suggested it. Both didn't solve my problem however.

Comment: You don't use `struct` in `stat getStat();` but you use it in `struct stat Person::getStat() {

}`.  Why?

Comment: Use `struct Person::stat Person::getStat() {` for the definition.
`

Comment: Because I was getting an error in the cpp file and putting struct solved it. However it didn't do anything for the header file so I figured I didn't have to.

Comment: `Person::~Person()
{
}` ->> `Person::~Person() = default;` you don't want a user defined function when you can get a trivial one.

Comment: In c++ you don't need to use `struct` to indicates that an identifier names a `struct` that's been previously declared. You have (had?) to in c but it's not a requirement in c++. It's necessary when you declare and define the `struct` but not when you use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be

```
Person::stat Person::getStat() {

}
```

Your version declares a new `struct stat` which isn't the same as `Person::stat`.

Comment: May I ask why it's Person::stat ? Is it because stat is a struct I defined in the header file?

Comment: @Kupperu It's because you defined `stat` *inside* `class Person`. If you had defined it outside you wouldn't need to say `Person::stat`. It has nothing to do with header files. C++ code is the same whether it's in a header file or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

`struct stat Person::getStat()` is a method that returns a `stat` that belongs to the global namespace, not to `Person`:

```
Person::stat Person::getStat()
```

Note that there is no `struct` here (to avoid declaring one). In C++, we don't use `struct` after the type has been declared.

Comment: Yeah I read about that in one of the posts on stackoverflow which was why I was confused as to why that seem to have temporarily solved a previous problem where I was getting an error for writing on the word stat. Since it seems to have fixed that error I kept it in.